# Pandas выборка данных и операции над ними

Tags: python, pandas

Мне нужно найти самый провальный фильм в интервале с 2010 по 2014 (минимальную разность бюджета и кассового сбора) по данным из csv-файла и вывести его название. Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать.

Мой код:

```python
import pandas as pd
sample = pd.read_csv("films.csv")
s1 = sample[(sample.release_year>2011) & (sample.release_year<2015)][['original_title','budget', 'revenue']]
print(s1)
print(str(s1['revenue']- s1['budget'])+ s1['original_title'])
print(min(s1['revenue']- s1['budget']))
```

Comment: Наверное, так: `print(s1.loc[(s1['revenue']- s1['budget']).min().index])`

Comment: 'print(s1.loc[(s1['revenue']- s1['budget']).min().index])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'index''

Comment: Попробуйте `.idxmin()`

Comment: Да, правильно будет `print(s1.loc[(s1['revenue']- s1['budget']).idxmin()])`, отсюда уже можете нужные значения вытянуть

Comment: Спасибо большое